# What are methods of identifying which amino acids are in a sample of protein?

Tags: organic-chemistry, identification

Are there any methods out there to identify which amino acids are in a sample of protein? Perhaps using NMR?

Comment: Can it be a destructive technique?

Comment: A destructive technique works fine, too.

Comment: What sample? One protein? And you'd only wish to know which rests of aminoacids are there? There *a lot* of methods for this, main one being just check in database. Seems you're kinda underestimating how much data about proteins is there already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a destructive technique that works with any mixture of proteins (i.e. to assess dietary questions), you could first hydrolyze the proteins into the amino acid building blocks. Then, you could separate them using chromatography (TLC, HPLC, GC), either as they are or after derivatizing functional groups to make them less polar.

If you are asking about a sample containing a single protein coming from an organism that has been sequenced, you could also enzymatically hydrolyze the protein (for instance with trypsin) and then subject fragments to mass spectroscopic analysis. A database search would identify the protein

For non-destructive techniques, you could start out with a natural abundance 2D NMR experiment (1H 15N HSQC), which gives you limited information (e.g. number of Asn/Gln). If you are interested in aromatic amino acids, the UV spectrum will be of interest. If you want to know whether there are free cysteins, there are coupling reagents you could use.

Comment: I'm curious whether a single crystal diffraction is ever used for amino acids identification. Or is it an overkill here?

Comment: Protein crystallography is too time consuming to use merely for amino acid identification. However, there a numerous examples where a pre-determined sequence was corrected by a medium-to-high 3D structure, especially back when DNA sequencing was less well developed and before proteins were over-expressed from a well-characterized gene. Also, amino acid modifications are sometimes detected by crystallography (mass spectrometry is usually easier and faster if you already suspect a given modification).

Answer (score 0):

Another technique is Shotgun mass spectrometry. For this, protein is digested with the protease (e.g. trypsin) and peptides are identified by mass / charge. Knowing the mass of peptides, the sequence of them can be found as well as the sequence of the whole protein. The last one will tell you about the exact amino acid composition of your protein.